# How to specify new subdirectory in routes for Yii 2 module?

Tags: yii, module, routes, yii2

I'm using Yii 2 and building a RESTful API inside a Yii 2 module called `apiv1`.

The file `config.php` for the module `apiv1` looks like this:

```
// ...
urlManager' => [
        // ...
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => [
                    'likes',
                ],
            ],
        ],
 ];
```

For instance, `GET /apiv1/likes` works, but I'd like to set up a route to handle `GET /api/v1/likes`.   How can this be done either individually or for the entire module as a general route from `api/v1` to `apiv1`?

Comment: are you trying to redirect the request coming to `/apivi/likes/` towards `/api/v1/likes` ?

Comment: Not redirect just re-route, but yes.  The module is named `apiv1`.  Requests to `GET /apiv1/likes` work fine, but I'd like requests to `GET /api/v1/likes` to be routed to the same controller/action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `prefix` attribute to customize your rest/UrlRule routes.

E.g., for your case, you should be able to do:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'likes',
    'prefix' => 'api/v1',
]
```

For more info, you can see the [REST routing guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing) and [yii-rest-rule API docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$patterns-detail) - in particular, see the `$patterns` and `$extraPatterns` properties for additional configuration options.

Comment: I did try adding the key/value pair `'prefix' => 'api/v1'` but no luck.  Some more info: The module is named `apiv1` and so requests to `GET /api/v1/likes` work okay.  Just looking for requests to `GET /api/v1/likes` to also route to this endpoint.

Comment: Paul, I had the same problem, and setting 'pluralize' => false  made 'prefix' to work.